# Write $(1, 2) + (1, 3) + (2, 1) + (2, 3) + (3, 1) + (3, 2)$ in Summation Form

Tags: summation, notation

I understand that I can write
$$
(1, 2) + (1, 3) + (2, 1) + (2, 3) + (3, 1) + (3, 2)
$$
as
$$
\sum_{i = 1, j = 1, i \ne j}^3 (i, j).
$$
Now, I add the condition that I would treat terms like $(1, 2)$ and $(2, 1)$  or $(3, 1)$ and $(1, 3)$ as the same element. Meaning, the sum now looks like:
$$
2(1, 2) + 2(1, 3) + 2(2, 3)
$$
How should I write the summation now?

Comment: If $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ are the same element, is the sum the same, or is it $(1,2) + (1,3) + (2,3)$? For the latter, change $\ne$ to $<$ below the summation sign

Comment: This a strange question. The previous comment is the key.

Comment: I've edited the question in light of the comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2*\sum_{j>i}\sum_{i=1}^2 (i,j)$$

Comment: I guess you need to add a condition that j would go to 3